# Cannot convert to binary image using otsu threshold

Tags: python, opencv, binary-image

I am trying to convert zebra crossing image into binary image through otsu method. At first I have counted threshold value of all the zebra crossing images in the folder and then append it to a list called `th_li=[]`

```
import cv2 as cv
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

dir3=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\bw"
images3=[cv2.imread(file,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) for file in sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\adaptive/*.jpg"))]
th_li=[]
for i,img in enumerate(images3):
    thresh = threshold_otsu(img)
    th_li.append(thresh)
```

After that using a two for-loop I have compared all the pixel value of the image with the corresponding threshold value. If the pixel value is less than the threshold value I have set it `0` otherwise `255`.
Then I have printed the image array, showing that the array contains only two value `0` or `255`. Then saved the image to another folder. Instead of showing `binary image` image looks like `yellowish`. But In the folder saved image is binary. Another problem is when I again print the binary image it contains value except `0` and `255`

```
images4=[cv2.imread(file,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) for file in sorted(glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\adaptive/*.jpg"))]

for k,img in enumerate(images4):

    for i in range(0,int(img.shape[0])):
        for j in range(0,int(img.shape[1])):
            if img[i][j]<int(th_li[k]):
                img[i][j]=0
            else:
                img[i][j]=255
    print(img)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
    plt.imshow(img)
    cv2.imwrite(dir3+"\\"+ "%06d.jpg" % k,img)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNBah.png)

After that when i read the image again it shows that array is not changed it all remains same.

Comment: Please show your all your code so that others can test with it and understand how they two sections work together. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For Otsu Threshold, just do `thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]`

Comment: @fmw42 thanks! i have tried this method but image array contains extra value except 0 and 255 .

Comment: I need to see your full code using that cv2.threshold all together, not separated or just parts of code. Also post the image to some free hosting service and put the URL in a comment.  Have you tried running the code for one image only with no loop. Test the basic concept and view each step to be sure there are no other errors and the images look as expected.

Comment: JPEG is lossy, which means it can change pixels to save space. If you want to retain your pixels accurately, use PNG which is lossless.

Comment: If your image is yellow, you need to use `cmap='gray'` when plotting to get a greyscale colormap rather than `viridis` yellow/green thing.

Comment: I believe that Mark Setchell's comment about saving to PNG rather than JPG is likely the issue. I overlooked that output format.